# How to catch the panel closing event

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#hide').on('click', function (e) {
   $('#current-pane).show()
  });
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group">
 <div class="panel panel-default" id="current-pane">
      This is First Panel
      <a href="#current-pane" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" id="hide">Finish Call</a>
    </div>
  
   <div class="panel panel-info hide" id="current-pane">
      Show me on close of first one
    </div>
  </div>
```

My requirement is to close the div once all action are done and show other div that choose another action.

Hence I thought bootstrap panel component will be helpful. Please not I am not looking for collapse effect. I am wants to do it in some animated way so that it give impression that working div is closed.

I am struggling to find the panel close event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div `id` must be unique, such as `current-pane1` , `current-pane2`, etc.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#hide').on('click', function (e) {
   $('#current-pane1').slideToggle();
   $('#current-pane2').removeClass("hide");
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group">
 <div class="panel panel-default" id="current-pane1">
      This is First Panel
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" id="hide">Finish Call</a>
    </div>
  
   <div class="panel panel-info hide" id="current-pane2">
      Show me on close of first one
    </div>
  </div>
```